# Which standard can we consider when writing QML?

Tags: qml, standard-library

For writing PHP code, programmers usually use PSR. For 
programming in QML, which standard should we consider that unites the code written by QML programmers.

Comment: I've found only [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-coding-conventions.html) link. But in general you should follow [Qt Coding Style](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Coding_Style)

Comment: yes, i see it before,its has not a name standard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a standard as such, but the best way that I know of to achieve what you're after is to use Qt Creator. The rules that it uses can likely only be found in its source code, but if you pay attention to the warnings that it produces, and use the `Tools > QML/JS > Reformat File` feature, you shouldn't have any problems.

The built-in coding style comes from `Tools > Options > Qt Quick > Code Style`.

Answer (score 2):

QML Coding Conventions http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-codingconventions.html

I guess you could follow JavaScript standard when writing QML.